# How to query for objects created in last 3 days? [parse.com]

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In my app users can post content and i want users to see content from the last 3 days. Is there a wherekey that I can have that only looks for posts from the last 3 days? I am using parse as my backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whereKey:greaterThan to solve this.

```
let threeDaysAgo = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-259200)
query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThan: threeDaysAgo)
```